# How to install libusb manually on macOS (without Homebrew)

Tags: libusb

I tried to download `libusb-1.0.0.dylib` and move it to `/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib` but Python still raised `usb.core.NoBackendError`. So after copying libusb to `/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib`, should I do something else? I know many of you will suggest installing it with Homebrew but I don't like Homebrew now. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pain... :)

- download libusb-1.0.26.tar.bz2 from https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/libusb.json aka "https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.26/libusb-1.0.26.tar.bz2"
- build with xCode to create the dynlib then archive / export the package.  There is an Xcode project inside the package... or compile in your own way make/build...
- copy the dynlib file to /opt/local/lib/libusb-1.0.dylib per hardcode in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb1/_libusb1.py ll 170 or choose 172 or 174... in method __getLibrary or symlink...
- Xcode will spit out wrong file name so ensure you rename the file accordingly when you copy it.  hope this helps.